# Complexity Analysis that makes every element in the array equal to largest element

Tags: java, algorithm, for-loop, time-complexity, big-o

What is the complexity of the given code as a function of the problem size n? Show the details
of your analysis.

```java
for (int i = 0; i < 2*n; i++)
{
    if (i == n)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
            for (int k = 0; k < i; k++)
                O(1)
    }
    else
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
            O(1)
    }
}
```

My thoughts so far:

The if statements could not always be true (could be log n)
Nested inner for loops are n^2.

Any help on how to solve it or how to proceed with it would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Without the `if(i == n) {}` , the number of operation is :

```
1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + ... + n*2

= (2n * (2n-1))/2
```

But at `i==n` , the number of operations is not `i` like the rest, it's `i²`.
So the final number of operations is :

```
((2n * (2n-1))/2) - n + n²
```

The Big O notation of the above is O(n²)

Comment: Is that the final time complexity of the whole function? And can you suggest me how I should be solving these kinds of functions/methods? Please and thank you.

Comment: Yes, O(n²) is my final answer. When the function is long/complex, just write down the equations (like I did above) and try transforming it by math.

Comment: Since `i == n` only once can't we say that that whole if block is O(1)?

Comment: No, cannot ignore the if block like that, the if block is 0(n^2) this case so it doesn't affect the whole code complexity, if that if block has O(n^3) then it will raise the total complexity to O(n^3).

Comment: @thienDX can you please check my updated answer and follow up.